# PhoneGap and Backbone Ajax call taking very long time

Tags: ios, ajax, backbone.js, cordova

I have a phonegap app built in Backbone and the ajax call is taking an incredibly long time. The load time is about 2min or longer to load a 46kb json file.

I am using the ios simulator which is pinging my local node.js server. The node.js server does a https.get() request to a weather service and returns it. The call works very quickly when I go to the url in a bowser.

Is the problem something to do with mobile memory management or underscore templating?  Help me! Thanks!

**// views/weather.js**

```
template: _.template($('#hero-1').html()),

render: function() {
    var view = this;
    $(this.el).html(this.template(view.model.toJSON()));
},

getWeatherData: function(lat, long){
      view.weatherModel = new this.model();
      view.weatherModel.fetch({
      data: {
        longitude: lat,
        latitude: long
      },
      success: function(data) {
          view.dataReturned(data.attributes);
          view.render();
      }
    });
 },
```

**//  models/weather.js**

```
return Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/weather',       

    parse: function(response){
        console.log("Parsing Response", response);
        response.weather.currently.avgTemp = Math.round(response.weather.currently.temperature);
        return response;
    }

});
```

**// html/Template**

```
<script type="text/template" id="hero-1">
   <div id="weather-temp" class="weather-temp">
      <%= weather.currently.avgTemp %>
   </div>
</script>
```

Thank you!

PLEASE NOTE:
If i do a standard call like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain:true,
            async: false,
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:3000/weather?longitude=-122.406417&latitude=37.785834",  
            success:function(data) {
               console.log('success');
               console.log(data); 
            }
         });
```

It just times out quickly but will work if i do it in the safari console for the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that XCODE will reset the ios Simulators location.

Open the Simulator:

window>Debug>Location>Custom Location

Set a new location.